# Adding roles to users in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So summary: I wanted to have two types of users which are teachers and students. They are all users and therefore inherit from the users controller. The problem is no about the controllers or classes existing, it's how to adapt them through a form and whether or not I'm missing anything. I'm not sure how to do a backend to radio buttons and have tried things from previous answers but they result in errors. Also, how do I change routes based on which role they select? I have a registrations controller to override Devise.

Here is my form:

```
<div class="authform">   <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.radio_button :role, 'student' %>
      <%= label :role_student, 'Student' %>

      <%= f.radio_button :role, 'teacher' %>
      <%= label :role_teacher, 'Teacher' %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit 'Sign Up', :class => 'button right' %>
        <% end %> </div>
```

I have a migration to add roles to users right here

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer
  end
end
```

This was my original attempt on changing routes when adding roles (from another stack overflow question)

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if params[:user][:role] == 'student'
      path_to_route = '/classrooms/index'
    elsif [:user][:role] == 'teacher'
      path_to_route = '/classrooms/new'
    else
      path_to_route = '/'
    end
    redirect_to path_to_route
  end

end
```

Finally, here is my user's controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  after_action :verify_authorized
  # before_filter :check_role

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    @posts = @user.posts
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    authorize @user
  end

  #def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #  if params[:user][:role] == 'student'
  #    path_to_route = '/classrooms/index'
  #  elsif [:user][:role] == 'teacher'
  #    path_to_route = '/classrooms/new'
  #  else
  #    path_to_route = '/'
  #  end
  #  redirect_to path_to_route
  #end


  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    # authorize @user
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

  def create_user_type
  end 

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end

  def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
  end

  def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
  end
end
```

I know this is a bit of a long post, but I'd appreciate any help. Thanks so much! I love the rails community.

Comment: I see your syntax with radio_button is wrong. You can follow [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button). Moreover, I want to know: `You don't know how to register new user with field role?`. Sr, I'm not clear your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use simple_form you can use a standard input and assign the options to `collection`.

#### with simple_form

```
<%= f.input :role, collection: [:admin, :subscriber, :poster] %>
```

#### without simple_form

```
<%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.map {|role| [role.titleize,role]}) %>
```

#### user.rb

```
enum role: [:admin, :subscriber, :poster]
```

Comment: This approach will also give you helper methods like `current_user.admin?` || `current_user.poster?`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I used without simple_form just so I didn't have to change my whole signup, but now I have another issue. It automatically appears with VIP or Admin, not teacher or student. Is this a Devise thing? How can I change it?

Comment: @MaxLeoTony try setting the value attribute on the input for role.

Comment: I already changed it to be: enum role: [:student, :teacher] , but the options still appear as VIP, admin. I think it might be something devise preset.

Comment: Update your model and view above @MaxLeoTony

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348282/is-this-a-devise-thing-setting-roles-to-users-after-signup