# Is this a devise thing? (setting roles to users after signup)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want 2 kinds of users, teacher and students. The problem now is that with my form displaying options it shows VIP and Admin, even though I set roles to teacher and students in the users controller. Is this a devise thing? Do I need to add a column to my migration?

Here is the part of the registration form. Ellipses mean skipping ahead.

```
<div class="authform">
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.map {|role| [role.titleize,role]}) %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit 'Sign Up', :class => 'button right' %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is my users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  after_action :verify_authorized
  # before_filter :check_role
  enum role: [:student, :teacher]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    @posts = @user.posts
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    authorize @user
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    # authorize @user
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

  def create_user_type
  end 

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end

  def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
  end

  def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
  end
end
```

All teachers and students have their own migrations, controllers and helper files. Here is the user migrations.

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end

class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer
  end
end
```

Sorry this is a long post, I'm just a bit confused as to why it doesn't have students and teachers as options and instead displays
[the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRJT0.png)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Roles are not a default in Devise.  Your code does not indicate a role attribute in your User table.  How was that added.  You can create your own column for roles (a standard is an admin attribute that is a boolean) or you can use an authorization gem like pundit.  Devise is built for authentication and you're looking for authorization (it's a pain to learn the difference at first)

Comment: Thats a bad way of assigning role, try using something on the line of STI with CanCan may be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a roles enum in the controller. This should be in the user model.